# How to enable an IIS web server to be accessed from outside?

Tags: iis, web-server, iis-7.5

I've setup an IIS web server. I can access its pages if I'm in the local server, but I'm unable to access it from outside.

For example trying to connect from another network to it (by using its public IP) returns nothing. Using an Apache server instead of an IIS works fine, the web server is accessible from outside.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a CNAME or A Record that is registered on a Public DNS system and resolvable by other DNS systems.

Assign this CNAME or A record as a Host Header to your website in IIS & bind it to the IP its bound to or all the IP's on the Server (Using "All Un-assigned" is only meant for troubleshooting, not good from a security perspective)

Try accessing this DNS record from a browser.

All this works, assuming you do not have any firewall restrictions in place.

hth's